# Apache virtualhost redirect to https

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, https

I have setup a VirtualHost to redirect to https. When I enter in the domain the ServerName it takes me to the https site. But it also takes me to the https site with any domain I enter. Why is this? Below is my config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName storage.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://storage.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Alias /files /var/www/files 
    ServerName storage.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud/

    <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All

        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
        </IfModule>

        SetEnv HOME /var/www/nextcloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/nextcloud
    </Directory> 

    # SSL
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/storage.example.com/fullchain.pem

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains;"     

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are you resolving the domains? Is this the site in your local network or on the public internet?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't specify any clause for it. Try with something like this instead of the permanent redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^storage.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://storage.example.com$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: This worked. Another thing when I go to any other domain it still takes me to the site. How can I get apache to take me to my site with the required domain (storage.example.com) not ab.example.com

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question. Could you reformulate it?